# dereference vs array access

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a class with this member function;

```
void AddTo(vertex** vrtList) {
  if(*vrtList != 0) {
    *vrtList->m_vrtLast = this;
  }
  m_vrtNext = *vrtList;  // save existing list, if any
  m_vrtLast = 0;
  *vrtList = this;
}
```

gcc gives me an error message;

> error: request for member ‘m_vrtLast’ in ‘* vrtList’, which is of non-class type ‘vertex*’

if I replace `*vrtList->m_vrtLast` with `vrtList[0]->m_vrtLast`, the compiler accepts it, and the code works fine.

Is this a bug (in gcc) or a feature (of C/C++)?

Comment: `(*vrtList)->m_vrtLast` may stand a better chance of doing what you want. And no, its not a bug; its a precedence issue.

Comment: Try to replace *vrtList->m_vrtLast with vrtList->m_vrtLast

Comment: You are correct, it does. As does vrtList[0]. So, the message is that postfix operators have precedence over prefix operators. Feature, not bug.

Comment: @user1929959 no. that would not give him what he wants.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a bug but is due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). The operator `->` has higher precedence than `*` so     `*vrtList->m_vrtLast` is the same as `*(vrtList->m_vrtLast)`, which is not what you intended.

`[]` and `->` have equal precedence but are read from left to right so the `[]` is encountered before the `->`.

Either use `[]` or `(*vrtList)->m_vrtLast`.

Comment: For what he wants, (*vrtList) is the only correct way. vrtList[0] is bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

It's about the priority of `operator*`.

`*vrtList->m_vrtLast` is not equivalent to `(*vrtList)->m_vrtLast` but rather to `*(m_vrtList->m_vertLast)` .

So you have to add parentheses accordingly.